# add a user in a group

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I would like to be able to add a user as a member into an excisting group (Newsletter).

With the code I have so far a new group is created with all the users and also the new member.

So , instead of inserting the user the code makes a new group (Newsletter) with the users.

```
<xp:this.data>
    <xp:dominoDocument var="usergroup"
        databaseName="contacts/webusers.nsf" formName="(46Group)"
        action="editDocument" computeWithForm="onsave">
    </xp:dominoDocument>
</xp:this.data>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:inputText id="fullname" value="#{viewScope.fullname}"></xp:inputText>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:br></xp:br>
<xp:button value="Add new user" id="button1">
<xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
<xp:this.action>
    <xp:actionGroup>

        <xp:executeScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:var who = @DbLookup("contacts/webusers.nsf","($VIMGroups)","Newsletter",3);
              var newone = getComponent("fullname").getValue();
              who = who + ", "+newone;
              usergroup.replaceItemValue("Members",who);
             usergroup.replaceItemValue("ListName","Newsletter");
             usergroup.save();}]]></xp:this.script>
        </xp:executeScript>
        <xp:openPage name="/login.xsp"></xp:openPage>
    </xp:actionGroup>
</xp:this.action>
</xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

**EDIT**

New code :

```
var ndb = session.getDatabase("","contacts/webusers.nsf")
var d = ndb.getView("($VIMGroups)").getDocumentByKey("Newsletter")
var newArr = new Array(d.getItemValue("Members")); 
newArr =newArr + ", another user";
d.replaceItemValue("Members",newArr);
d.save(true,false);
```

As per suggestion of Thomas I changed my code.
The user is added to the members, but it is added x times. and x is the number of excisting members. I also tried to add the member with push, but this doesn't work. How can I add a member in the array in a proper way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "usergroup" data source is not connected to the group document so the data source creates a new document when you load the page

You need to connect your data source to the group document, once you have that set you do not need to do the dblookup, you can just add the new user to the document data source field and save it.

You should be able to connect your data source doing something like this, (not tested)

```
var ndb = session.getDatabase("","contacts/webusers.nsf")
var d = ndb.getView("($VIMGroups)").getDocumentByKey("Newsletter")
return d.getUniversalID()
```

Here is some working code you can use in your button, I had to remove the data source as I was not allowed to save it due to security,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:inputText id="inputText1"></xp:inputText>
    <xp:button value="Add new user" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:var ndb = sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess.getDatabase("server","names.nsf")
var d = ndb.getView("($VIMGroups)").getDocumentByKey("Newsletter")
var members = d.getItemValue("Members")
members.add(getComponent("inputText1").getValue())
d.replaceItemValue("Members",members)
d.save()}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: I tried this, but nothing is appended .....
var ndb = session.getDatabase("","contacts/webusers.nsf")
var d = ndb.getView("($VIMGroups)").getDocumentByKey("Newsletter")
var newArr = new Array(d.getItemValue("Members")); 
newArr.push("another user");
d.save();

Comment: If you're amending the datasource, you'll also need to set ignoreRequestParams="true".
Your code in the comment above won't update the document, because you're not changing the "Members" item. You're pulling (copying) the values into a new array instead and updating that array.

Comment: Paul? was this suppose to be a comment on the question?